# Large datasets for graphs

Tags: graph, dataset

I'm working on K shortest path algorithm and i need graph datasets with **number of nodes** around **2000 or 3000** for test the algorithm's running time. I have searched alot and i couldn't able to find the datasets which exactly suits my requirement.

While googled i found lot of datasets on socail networks, wikipedia, etc which consits of numbers and strings. I don't need those datasets.

I need them as follows:

```
6
1 2 12
1 4 14
2 3 23
3 4 34
3 0 30 
4 5 45
5 0 50
```

where 1st line says no. of nodes, and 1st two columns say the edge between two nodes and 3rd column is weight of that edge.

It would be great if anyone has such **datasets** please provide or even if you know any **`datafile generator tools`** for using graphs?

Comment: Why not just convert the found datasets from their format to the format you want or simply write a reader for the data set that you can just switch to when the dataset is in that format?

Comment: the datasets i found consists of around 5k to 10k edges (lines) and how could and convert them ? I really didn't know how to write that reader for.

Comment: Well, you'd probably need to write code to convert them (the effort between that and writing a reader is probably roughly the same). Currently you read you file, so changing this to read a file in a different format shouldn't be too difficult. It should be very easy to write code to generate a graph, just generate a random amount of edges between random vertices with random weights (although this may not really show the worst-case of your program). If you've attempted any of the approaches I mentioned and you're having any specific problems, you can post another question here asking for help.

Comment: No, i haven't attempted for coding to generate file. I have kept that as worstcase bcz presently i don't need to do that. So, i'm looking for available datasets. 
If i haven't found any, then i might be i'll do so.. Anyhow thanks for ur suggestions.